# Init SQLite Db with docker-compose

Tags: docker, sqlite, dockerfile

I'm trying to init a SQLite database when I create my container using Docker-Compose.
The issue I have is that the init file, with my dB structure is well copied to the container, in the right directory, but when the RUN instruction launches the sqlite3 command, it does not fail, but it does not do anything, so the database file is not created.
And when the container is up and running, if I type the strictly same command, it works perfectly, meaning the dB file is created and the structure is good.

Here is a sample of my Dockerfile :

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install netcat gcc sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nano \
  && apt-get clean

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./system_init/db/init_db.sql ./system_init/db/init_db.sql
RUN cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql
```

Once the docker-compose process is launched, the init_db.sql is copied in the right location, but it seems the sqlite3 command runs, but I don't have any warning.
If I put an error in the sql file, the docker-compose build fails, saying that there's an error in my SQL schema.
So the command seems to be executed, but the db file is not created...

Without error (database.db is not created):

```
 => [engine:latest  9/18] COPY ./system_init/db/init_db.sql ./system_init/db/init_db.sql                                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => [engine:latest 10/18] RUN cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql                                                                                                                                          1.2s
 => [engine:latest 11/18] COPY ./wait-for-it.sh .
```

With error in the SQL schema :

```
 => [engine:latest  9/18] COPY ./system_init/db/init_db.sql ./system_init/db/init_db.sql                                                                                                                                            0.4s
 => ERROR [engine:latest 10/18] RUN cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql                                                                                                                                    1.4s
------
 > [engine:latest 10/18] RUN cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql:
#26 0.989 Error: near line 25: near "CREATE": syntax error
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql]: exit code: 1
```

If I execute the **cd ./system_init/db/ && sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql** command on the container once it's up, it works fine, and the database.db file is created.

```
MacBook:docker-sqlite$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container sqlite  Started                                                                                                                                                                 2.6s
MacBook:docker-sqlite$ docker exec -it sqlite bash
root@480319381c17:/db# ls
Dockerfile  init_db.sql
root@480319381c17:/db# sqlite3 database.db < init_db.sql
root@480319381c17:/db# ls
Dockerfile  init_db.sql  database.db
```

In the docker-compose file, there's nothing special. A volume is associated with this container for data persistence.
Here is the docker-compose.yml content :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  engine:
    build: ./app
    image: engine:latest
    container_name: myengine
    depends_on:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
      - ./workflows:/usr/src/app/resources/workflows_files
      - ./configurations:/usr/src/configurations
    ports:
      - 8080:8000
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network
    env_file: 
      - ./env/engine.env
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - APP_NAME="Local Engine"
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your final setup references a Docker Compose setup; can you include the `docker-compose.yml` file in the question?  In particular, do you have `volumes:` hiding the image content?

Comment: Hi David, Just add the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Yup, the `volumes:` are replacing everything in `/usr/src/app` in the container (including the prepopulated SQLite file) with content from the host.  Can you at least delete the bind mount targeting `/usr/src/app`?